# Eclipse CDT Binary not found - Mac OS X Lion

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

On my MacBook Air I need to use Eclipse to make some c++ programs for school. So I downloaded Eclipse for C++ from the eclipse.org and made a little Hello World program. However, when I try to run the program, it just gives me the error "Launch failed. Binary not found".

When I try to build the program, this is the output:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorldC ****

make all 

Cannot run program "make": Unknown reason
Error: Program "make" is not found in PATH

PATH=[/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

**** Build Finished ****
```

However, I tried to make a hello world application in Xcode and that works perfect...

Unfortunately, I cannot use Xcode because the teacher is only allowing Eclipse projects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem is that you can install the latest Xcode (4.3) only from the app store, and by default it seems like the c++ compiler is only accessible through Xcode, to solve this you need to:

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to Preferences
3. Go to Downloads
4. Install Command Line Tools

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "UNIX Development Tools" are installed with the Xcode installer.

Comment: I installed Xcode from the mac app store, so I didn't get an installer, but I assume the UNIX Development Tools are installed since I can run c++ programs from Xcode, right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Eclipse here, but on my Mac book which make gives me:

```
correa$ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

which is one of the paths it's looking for.
If I remember correctly, it was installed simply installing Xcode from the app store. You should try to check if make is really installed in your system, if not, you could try reinstalling xcode to see if it fixes the problem.

Hope this little bit can give you a starting point. Can't yet comment on the question, otherwise would have just made a comment.