# Eclipse CDT for Windows 8.1 on VM - Binary not found/HelloWorld

Tags: c, macos, binary, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to make Eclipse running work on my HelloWorld example but I always got "Binary not found".

I tried to change the Binary parser to PE Windows Parser without success on the project properties. I also tried some tips found on the internet without success (I've tried a lot of them so I don't remember well which one I tried... sorry)

I'm working on Windows 8.1 on Parallel VM for MAC OS.

I'm aware that kind of problem has already been answered (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418928/eclipse-cdt-binary-not-found-mac-os-x-lion)), but I wonder if the solution I tried didn't work because of my Parallel Virtual Machine on Mac?

Comment: It' totally unclear what is your setup and the problem. You are mixing up things here. The binary which is not found has no relation to the binary parser Eclipse is using. I don't understand where is your compiler/Eclipse environment is running. On the MacOS under VM? Or in Windows? What kind of toolchain are you using?

Comment: Hello, I'm working on a Windows 8.1 virtual machine on my Mac. I tried to put all the tools I need on windows 8.1. I just installed on it make-3.81 and gcc-4.6.4-32.
On the C/C++ Build>Settings, I've checked PE Windows Parser box and moved it up at the top.

Comment: None binary file is created when I start the build button.
On my console I have the message : (Cannot run program "make": Launching failed)

I keep looking for a solution, thanks for your attention to my problem Eugene.